# How to run a PowerShell Script after Inno Setup installer

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, inno-setup

I have a PowerShell script that modifies some preference files that I'm trying to have run after my Inno Setup installer is completed. Haven't found a working solution for this yet. My goal is to embed this in the file, or code, so I don't have to ship multiple files, just the installer. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To execute a command after an installation finishes, add an entry to [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection).

---

If the PowerShell code is trivial, you can execute it without any script file directly from PowerShell command-line with [`-Command` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh#-command---c):

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; Parameters: \
  "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('my.ini', 'foo=1')"; \
  WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
```

Regarding the [`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-executionpolicy-executionpolicy): As you will be executing this on systems you do not control, it's likely that some/most will have the default PowerShell settings, that restricts execution of commands. To overcome that you need this switch.

---

If you need a script file, you need to "install" it (e.g. to a temporary folder of the installation) and run it from there.

```
[Files]
Source: "setup.ps1"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{tmp}\setup.ps1"""; \
  WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
```

(the temporary folder gets automatically deleted when the installer finishes)

Comment: Thank you, the second method worked perfectly! I would like to embed the whole thing, but my PowerShell script has so many levels of quotes and escape characters already, was having trouble escaping them all another level.