# How to execute a PowerShell Script Using innoSetup

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

I am trying to import a PowerShell module using inno Setup and execute with the following code but when I run it doesn't run the script with the parameters I have mentioned someone please help me out what I am doing wrong.

```
    [Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
Parameters: "New-ChromeExtension -ExtensionID 'agckcglooaipjmbeipibmbffnogjfdfb' -Hive Machine -File ""{app}\New-ChromeExtension.ps1"""; \
WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
```

Here are the commands to execute from direct PowerShell

```
Import-Module C:\Scripts\New-ChromeExtension.ps1
New-ChromeExtension -ExtensionID 'bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj' -Hive Machine
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer provided to me here had an example of using PowerShell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64970085/2287576 I don't know if it helps you.

Comment: See [How to run a PowerShell Script after Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56419077/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have tried the link you have mentioned but its not working as expected, Am I using the proper parameters which I mentioned in the question.!

Comment: So show us what did you try based on the link. The command-line syntax in your question is different than what my answer shows and it's simply wrong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl This is what I have tried also I dont know that i am using the proper format from that link

`[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe";
  Parameters: \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command New-ChromeExtension -ExtensionID 'agckcglooaipjmbeipibmbffnogjfdfb' -Hive Machine""{app}\New-ChromeExtension.ps1"""; \
  WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden`

Comment: I do not see any `Import-Module` there. The `\"` looks wrong too.

Comment: The Truth is I have no idea how to use it so tired googling and found that answer based on that answer I tried but it did not worked so I thought its better to get some help from experts and learn from my mistakes, Here what I am trying to do I have to import a ps1 module from C Drive and execute that with the following command ( New-ChromeExtension -ExtensionID 'bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj' -Hive Machine ) when I do it manually the script works and with the current code I have its not working so please help me out.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You know what commands to use interactively in PowerShell. So why don't you use the same commands, when trying to automate it? `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module C:\Scripts\New-ChromeExtension.ps1 ; New-ChromeExtension -ExtensionID 'bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj' -Hive Machine`

Comment: Usually a `.ps1` file isn't a module (usually modules are `.psm1`). So I don't know why you need `Import-Module` before running your script command; your PowerShell code seems to be incorrect (but hard to say since I can't see your script).